# Is an Asus USB-N13 compatible with Linux Mint 14

Tags: wireless-networking, linux-mint, asus-laptop, adapter

I'm looking for a wireless adapter for my computer running Linux Mint 14 and would like to know if an [Asus USB-N13](http://www.asus.com/Networking/USBN13/) is compatible.

Comment: I have it and it works fine.  But voting to close as this is basically a buying recommendation (Against the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq)),  but on the edge since it asks about compatibility too.

Comment: How can something be against frequently asked question

Answer (score 1):

You could try looking at the support pages for the adaptor in question.

http://www.asus.com/Networking/USBN13/#support_Download_5

That page has a Linux option in the OS selection drop down and there is actually a driver there so one Linux in general is supported and potentially should work.

As to whether *your* distro has direct support, that is a question for your distro maintainers.